# CSS overflows and horizontal scrollbars

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to build a simple jQuery panel slider on a website (two in fact). I'm not much of an expert when it comes to JS/Javascript, and for some reason I can't remove the horizontal scrollbar on my site.

http://www.visioncreativegroup.com.au/demos/dd/

The slider areas are within the Gallery and Feature Project sections.

I've tried adding overflow: hidden to the slideshow(s) wrapping divs, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Any advice?

:)

Comment: I don't think it's the slideshows that are causing the scrollbar to appear - I'd assume if it was all three images from the slideshow would be displayed horizontally and you could scroll through them, but the slideshow seems to work fine.

Comment: What do you want? You don't want horizontal scrollbar? or something else? As Michael Peterson mentioned `I don't think it's the slideshows that are causing the scrollbar to appear `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the CSS propertie **"overflow-x: hidden"** to **"BODY"**. Not for IE8-

This will work, but will be a hack. There is something wrong with your structure to get that horizontal scroll and unfortunatelly i can't check further at this time.

Answer (score 1):

In your style.css

Replace this code

```
body {
    font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz';
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: 400;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tim, in your style.css there are two strange widths in classes:

```
#gallery .panels {
    -moz-transition: margin-left 0.8s ease 0s;
    margin-left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 4320px;
}
```

and

```
#project .panels {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 2880px;
}
```

They are causing the scrollbar.

Remove them, or, if you want to keep them, apply the method everyone else suggesting:

`overflow-x:hidden` to the body

Answer (score 0):

NOT A HACK! I fixed your problem by applying

```
.wrap {
  position: relative;
}
```

Invariably applied as standard in pre-rolled grid systems. Turns out that's what it'll take for your browser to pay attention to the overflow: hidden on that element.